# Explain some scala code - beginner

Tags: scala

I've encountered this scala code and I'm trying to work out what its doing except the fact it returns an int. I'm unsure of these three lines :

```
  l match {
  case h :: t =>
  case _ => 0
```

Function :

```
def iterate(l: List[Int]): Int = 
  l match {
  case h :: t =>
    if (h > n) 0 
  case _ => 0
}
```

Comment: Go through the Tour of Scala  http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120. Also, http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/pattern_matching.html

Comment: Your code should not compile because `if (h > n) 0` is not of type `Int` (missing else case with type `Int`) and `n` is unknown.

Comment: `head :: tail` pattern matches on a List. For `List(1, 2, 3)` it is `1 :: List(2, 3)`, for `List(1)` it is `1 :: List()` (or `1 :: Nil`), for `List()` it doesn't match. The `_` matches "anything else".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you define a function called `iterate` and you specified the return type as `Int`. It has arity 1, parameter `l` of type `List[Int]`.

The `List` type is prominent throughout functional programming, and it's main characteristics being that it has efficient prepend and that it is easy to decompose any `List` into a head and tail. The head would be the first element of the list (if non-empty) and the tail would be the rest of the `List`(which itself is a `List`) - this becomes useful for recursive functions that operate on `List`.

The `match` is called pattern matching.. it's essentially a `switch` statement in the C-ish languages, but much more powerful - the `switch` restricts you to constants (at least in C it does), but there is no such restriction with `match`.

Now, your first `case` you have `h :: t` - the `::` is called a "cons", another term from functional programming. When you create a new `List` from another `List` via a prepend, you can use the `::` operator to do it.

Example:

```
val oldList = List(1, 2, 3)
val newList = 0 :: oldList // newList == List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

In Scala, operators that end with a `:` are really a method of the right hand side, so `0 :: oldList` is the equivalent of `oldList.::(0)` - the `0 :: oldList` is syntactic sugar that makes it easier to read.

We could've defined `oldList` like

```
val oldList = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

where `Nil` represents an empty `List`. Breaking this down into steps:

1. `3 :: Nil` is evaluated first, creating the equivalent of a `List(3)` which has head 3 and empty tail.
2. 2 is prepended to the above list, creative a new list with head 2 and tail `List(3)`.
3. 1 is prepended, creating a new list with head 1 and tail `List(2, 3)`.

The resulting `List` of `List(1, 2, 3)` is assigned to the `val oldList`.

Now when you use `::` to pattern match you essentially decompose a `List` into a head and tail, like the reverse of how we created the `List` above. Here when you do

```
l match {
  case h :: t => ...
}
```

you are saying decompose `l` into a head and tail if possible. If you decompose successfully, you can then use these `h` and `t` variables to do whatever you want.. typically you would do something like act on `h` and call the recursive function on `t`.

One thing to note here is that your code will not compile.. you do an `if (h > n) 0` but there is no explicit `else` so what happens is your code looks like this to the compiler:

```
if (h > n) 0
else { }
```

which has type `AnyVal` (the common supertype of `0` and "nothing"), a violation of your `Int` guarentee - you're going to have to add an `else` branch with some failure value or something.

The second `case _ =>` is like a `default` in the `switch`, it catches anything that failed the head/tail decomposition in your first `case`.

Your code essentially does this:

1. Take the `l` `List` parameter and see if it can be decomposed into a head and tail.
2. If it can be, compare the head against (what I assume to be) a variable in the outer scope called `n`. If it is greater than `n`, the function returns 0. (You need to add what happens if it's not greater)
3. If it cannot be decomposed, the function returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is called pattern matching. It's like a `switch` statement, but more powerful.

Some useful resources:

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-4